# Ordering query results conditionally

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have to repost this again as my last posts answer was not the real solution:

I have Posts and Comments in my Rails app. I want to display Posts ordered by most recent activities, meaning Posts with a recent comment come first.

I have this SQL and several Problems at the moment:

```
Post.left_outer_joins(:comments).
order('comments.created_at DESC, posts.created_at DESC').
uniq
```

As you can see it joins the two tables, orders the results and picks unique entries out of it

The Problems is:

- If Posts have no Comments then those Posts appear allways as first in the descending order they are created, but I want the posts to be in the order of recent activity.

Just like a Forum which sorts the postings of the users after recent activities in them

I would like to merge the columns `comments.created_at` and `posts.created_at` into the column `posts.created_at` with the value:

- `comments.created_at` if not null else
- `posts.created_at`if there are no comments

and then order the whole query after `posts.created_at`

I would really appreciate your help for solving this problem, thank you

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: postgresql is it but I allready have an in-code solution with plain ruby

Comment: if you want to paginate and have a big data set you better do it on the database level

Comment: thank you for your solution that was my intention in the first place because Ruby is really slow, so this was only an emergency solution. But thanks to you I now have the optimal solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do in this case is to sort by the maximum of both.

```
Post.left_outer_joins(:comments).
order('GREATEST(comments.created_at, posts.created_at) DESC').
uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did in Ruby:

```
@posts = Post.where(category: params[:category])
@posts.each do |p|
  p.created_at = p.comments.count == 0 ? p.created_at : p.comments.last.created_at
end
@posts = @posts.sort_by { |k| k[:created_at] }.reverse
@posts = @posts.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

Answer (score 0):

**app/models/post.rb**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
end
```

**app/models/comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
end
```

**db/schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2018_09_20_081230) do

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "comment_content"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "post_id"
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "post_title"
    t.text "post_content"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

**Query**

```
Post.includes(:comments).order('comments.created_at DESC')
```

**Test Environment:**

- Ruby 2.3.5
- Ruby 5.2.1

**UPDATE**

```
Post.joins('LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.post_id = posts.id').group('posts.id').order('COALESCE(MAX(comments.created_at), posts.created_at) DESC')
```

Or

```
Post.find_by_sql('SELECT posts.* FROM posts LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.post_id = posts.id GROUP BY posts.id ORDER BY COALESCE(MAX(comments.created_at), posts.created_at) DESC')
```

Comment: This query does exactly the same as mine plus with the ``left_outer_join`` which is also inferred with `includes` there are results without the ``comments.created_at`` column when a post has no comments....so this is not the answer I look for

Comment: @IljaKO You want with posts with recent activity followed by posts with no comment? Or no comment appears first followed by with recent activity?

Comment: I maybe explained it too much and should just have said: Look how an online forum behaves. The posts in Forums are ordered after recent activity: A post is on top when it was just created right now or if a comment was posted in a post right now. This is what I understand under recent activity, just like a normal forum app behaves